# testing checked attribute on a radio button using jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

Using Angular 8.

Playing around with Jasmine where I have a basic loop of radio buttons. I want to test a function that sets the checked attribute to a (x)th radio button contained within the loop. (x)th is determined by `this.startingCarType`

I'm currently getting false and null test error responses.
What is the best way to approach this.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

I have noticed that changing `[checked]="setChecked(i)"` to `checked="true"` results in passing tests, which makes sense. So the question / issue is around `[checked]="setChecked(i)"`

HTML

```
<div class="cars">
  <div *ngFor="let car of arrayOfCarType; let i = index">
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="cars"
      [id]="i"
      [checked]="setChecked(i)"
    />
    <label [for]="i">Car Type {{ i }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
this.arrayOfCarTypes = new Array(4).fill({})
this.startingCarType = 0
....
public setChecked(i: number) {
  return this.startingCarType === i;
}
```

SPEC

```
let component: CarComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CarComponent>;
let input: any;
let startingCarType: number;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [CarComponent]
  }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CarComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.arrayOfItems = new Array(4).fill({});
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

describe('setChecked()', () => {
  it('should set checked attribute', () => {

    startingCarType = 0;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.cars div input[id="0"]');

    expect(input.checked).toBeTruthy(); // Expected false to be truthy
    expect(input.getAttribute('checked')).toEqual('true'); // Expected null to equal 'true'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
I was missing one key point. Setting the `component.startingCarType` value.

SPEC

```
...
it('should set checked attribute', () => {

  component.startingCarType = 0;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.cars div input[id="0"]');

  expect(input.checked).toBeTruthy(); // passes

  });
```